# jQuery slider and swf

Tags: jquery, flash, slider, bxslider

I'm using [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/) jQuery script on my personal website. I have been able to use it with SWF files. It works! But the swf are running all in the meantime... also when they are not visible.

**So I'd like to stop the swf files when they are not visible.**

Two ways (I suppose):

1): use a **flashvar** and work on this var inside the swf (I can, I'm a Flasher).
    But: how to send the flashvar from jQuery script to the php page? I found similar discussions, but I need a little more help on this specific script.

or:

2): kill, **delete** or something similar the hidden swf and reload it when is his turn to be shown.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a LONG time since I did any Flash, so I'm not 100% sure about the stop and play calls, but your document ready code should look something like this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slider1').bxSlider({
        onAfterSlide: function(currentSlideNumber, totalSlideQty, currentSlideHtmlObject) {
            switch (currentSlideNumber) {
                case 0:
                    $(".slideshow_elemento object")[0].SetVariable("_play", true);
                    $(".slideshow_elemento object")[1].SetVariable("_play", false);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $(".slideshow_elemento object")[0].SetVariable("_play", false);
                    $(".slideshow_elemento object")[1].SetVariable("_play", true);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Then, in each Flash movie you need to add a watch to the variable _play...

```
function playChange(prop, oldval, newval) {
    if (_play) {
        Play();
    } else {
        Stop();
    }
    return newval;
}
var _play = false;
this.watch("_play", playChange);
```

That may not be correct - you'll probably need to play around with the actionscript a bit to get it correct.

Comment: Thanks so much Archer.

Yes I think that the actioscript part is in old as2, my flash now are in as3. But I can fight with it!

The monster for me is with the 'document ready'. To explain myself, I have to figure where to paste your code in the existing cose [(this)](https://github.com/wandoledzep/bxslider/blob/master/source/jquery.bxSlider.js). Tonight i'm going to try.

Comment: You don't need to paste it in there. It goes in your web page. Just replace the $(document).ready in your home page with the one above. I took yours and modified it to get the above code.

Comment: Great (thanks!). Now document ready is correctly on. It's [online](http://www.riscovo.com/a-bank-of-ideas/), you can see the result in source code, do you think is ok now with the non Flash part of the issue?

Comment: Hum Archer, with this new document class the bxSlider crashes after the first cycle of slideshow. Lok at [this](http://www.riscovo.com/ready-2-drive/) page (in this page no swf, just jpgs... could be easyer to understand).

Comment: I can't see any errors that would stop the slideshow working with jpeg images, but you _are_ getting errors for trying to use the SetVariable method on them.  It obviously won't work as they are jpegs not swf files.  

Incidentally, I ran the SetVariable command in the console to see if it would stop the flash movie playing and it didn't, once you make that work then you should be sorted.  We can look at the jpeg issue as a separate issue.

Comment: That's clear! =) Sorry: I did not imagined to specify my post are containing sometimes Swfs and sometimes Jpgs/Gifs. But I also notice the same 'bug' in the [swf pages](http://www.riscovo.com/a-bank-of-ideas/). Anyway, the flash issue: I would like to don't abuse of your time, so in these hours I've been working on an as3 translation of your as2 very good idea. I'm testing on the above swf page. In this moment I can't correctly get your _play variable in flash (i renamed it in: _attivo). So I'll try more. Should I post my as code in an answer here below?

Comment: Ok, after lot of googling I understood what exactly is needed. I need to get the AS3 [ExternalInterface class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) working in a way that can combine with Javascript metod you suggested me (the SetVariable, placed in the document ready of the bxSlider). Very very hard issue for my creaive brain!! But I'll try more, startig from this.

Comment: If it were a few years ago I'd be able to help you out - I was all over Flash back then.  As always though, Google is your friend.  Sounds like you're making good progress :)

Comment: Yeah hehehe =). Look, the question was going to be too hard for my skills, so I decided to stop in and try again when I'll be more free on my work. You have been very kind anyway. =)